# Parallel.Foreach how to create local variable in different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task, parallel.foreach

```
 Parallel.ForEach(array_ptr, 
                new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 },                     
                (current_ptr, state, index) => after_di(current_ptr)    
            );
```

And the function after_di:

```
private IntPtr after_di(IntPtr in_ptr)
    {
        IntPtr det_ptr = det(in_ptr);
        free_image_pointer(in_ptr);
        IntPtr adp_ptr = adaptive_scaler(det_ptr, 1280, 720, 1, 1, 70);
        free_image_pointer(det_ptr);
        IntPtr cmu_ptr = cmu(adp_ptr, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        free_image_pointer(adp_ptr);
        return cmu_ptr;
    }
```

The problem is when the Parallel run in same thread, the free_image_pointer function (free allocate memory in dll C code) does not free the right pointer, so it cause error. I want each IntPtr det_ptr, IntPtr adp_ptr, IntPtr cmu_ptr is different on each item loop. Is it possible?

**Update test:**
While debugging, I see the problem happens with only det() function. So i made some tests with the det() function only. In my main function, this is what I've done:

```
  IntPtr main_out0_ptr = det(temp_rgb0);
  IntPtr main_out1_ptr = det(temp_rgb1);
```

The above code are fine. But if i create new thread on each funtion like that:

```
Thread th1 = new Thread(() =>  det(temp_rgb0));
th1.Start();
Thread th2 = new Thread(() => det(temp_rgb1));
th2.Start();
```

The error occur, it said: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I still don't know why this happened.

Comment: Are you sure the C functions are thread-safe?

Comment: Hi svick, yes, because the C function is just pure algorithm, some math and pixel array pointer,...to process image, it's not related to thread.

Comment: It looks like `det()` is allocating memory. Are you sure the memory allocator you're using (probably `malloc`) is thread-safe? Though it seems Visual C++ only has thread-safe C runtime [since VS 2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I think the det() is thread-safe, because I've already run it multi-thread using it's exe console

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to suggest without looking at implementation of `det(),adaptive_scaler()`... but `ThreadLocal<T>` is designed for a scenario like this (where each thread needs to have a local copy of a value.

Here is [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx), and there is a code example demonstrating how it works.

Comment: Those functions are called from DLLs writen in C, just process image and return the image pointer, actually an IntPtr. And the process is sequence, det then adaptive_scaler,... so I need to free the pointer after used because the limit of ram.

Comment: Alright, then ThreadLocal won't help in this scenario. What makes you believe "problem is when the Parallel run in same thread" ?

Comment: The error is: "try to access protected memory" so I think it's cross-thread problem. when I don't use the parallel loop, just call "after_di" 2 times each by each with each item in the list (because my "array_ptr" list only consist of 2 IntPtr, so the loop is only run with 2 items), it is running fine without error.

Comment: I haven't done much work around COM/Pointers, but in my knowledge some COM objects are thread aware. Which means, the library you are using may not be able to access a object if it's called from a thread different than the one which created the object. Read: Thread-agnostic vs thread-aware.

Comment: A simple test could be to call ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(()=>after_di(anyValidPointer)) , and see if you get the same error.

Comment: @ManishBasantani This doesn't look like COM.

Comment: Hi, actually what I need is to create different IntPtr variable in different thread, because the parallel some time create different thread, some time use the same thread so I think it use the same IntPtr variable too.